# Google Analytics Event - Date range value

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have two date selectors on my website (from:to) and I would like to track the date range selected from these selectors. So if a user enters, for example, From [May 6th, 2018] To [June 6th, 2018], I would like to be able to track the range of date that was selected in Google Analytics.

Is there some way to do this? I thought about Event Value, but this is only for integers so it does not really apply...

Answer (score 0):

`Event Category`, `Event Action`, and `Event Label` accept strings; and `Event Value` accepts integers. Therefore there is no ready made solution to track date values.

The best option is to track dates as strings in `Event Label` - e.g. `2018-05-08`